# numprint: suppress leading 0 in exponent

Tags: numprint

I us `\numprint` to pretty-print numbers in the scientific notation. For some reason, the numbers I have have a 2-digits exponents, padded with zeros in front, like:

```
\numprint{1.3e02}
```

With this command the output looks like

```
1.3 x 10^(02)
```

I would like instead to automatically drop the 0 in front, so to get something like

```
1.3 x 10^2
```

Is this possible within the `numprint` package?

Comment: Is employing the `siunitx` package and using its `\num` macro an option for you?

Comment: @Mico It is an option, but I would prefer to stick to the ```numprint``` package, if that is possible at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This patches `\numprint` to apply `\number` when the exponent is stored for later processing. But I recommend switching to `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\numprint}
 {\nprt@testsign{exponent}{\nprt@exponent}}
 {\expanded{\noexpand\nprt@testsign{exponent}{\number\nprt@exponent}}}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\numprint{1.3e02}

\numprint{1.3e-02}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If using the `siunitx` package and its `\num` macro is an option for you, it's not too difficult to provide the options that are needed to make the output of `\num` look just the same as that of `\numprint`, in both text and math mode, *except* that leading zeros in the exponent will be removed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cfr-lm} % use oldstyle numerals in text mode
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}, 
         exponent-product = \cdot,
         detect-mode}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l >{$}l<{$} @{}}
\numprint{1.3e02} & \numprint{1.3e02} \\
\num{1.3e02}      & \num{1.3e02}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```